# "> expected" error on creating a class with generics

Tags: java, class, generics, generic-collections

I am creating a class with Generics

```
public class MyEntry<K,Set<V extends SpecificEntry>> extends TimerTask{
//
}
```

But this is generating an error > expected
As I see, the diamond operator is closed properly

If I make it

```
public class MyEntry<K,Set> extends TimerTask{
//
}
```

It works, but I want the second argument to be a set of a specific type.

What should be done to get this right?

Comment: In the very first java generation with generics one had to place a space between `>`s. But it seems Jiri Tousek has found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the second generic parameter to be a Set of a given type you need:

```
public class MyEntry<K,V extends Set<? extends SpecificEntry>> extends TimerTask
```

BTW, `public class MyEntry<K,Set> extends TimerTask` doesn't work the way you think. `Set` in your case is the name of the second generic type parameter, and has no relation to `java.util.Set`.

Comment: Your info on Set is Interesting. What I need is a java.util.Set

Comment: @rajesh Is that a question? What I meant is that in `MyEntry<K,Set>`, `Set` is just a name, which does not represent the `java.util.Set` interface.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is not to use parameter for the `Set` generic type, but instead parameterize just the *element type of the Set*:

```
public class MyEntry<K, V extends SpecificEntry> extends TimerTask{
    //
}
```

and then use `Set<V>` where needed.

Comment: But my requirement needs the second parameter to be a Set

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to include a minimal example of how you intend to use the type parameter so it's clear why you need `<V extends Set>` as a type parameter.